# Compile time error when passing object as parameter in plsql procedure

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

testing to pass an object as a parameter in pl/SQL procedure but getting the error.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE address_obj AS OBJECT 
(house_no varchar2(10), 
 street varchar2(30), 
 city varchar2(20), 
 state varchar2(10), 
 pincode varchar2(10) 
) NOT FINAL; 
/


create table billing_address (house_no varchar2(10), 
 street varchar2(30), 
 city varchar2(20), 
 state varchar2(10), 
 pincode varchar2(10) 
);

create procedure save_address   ( pi_address in  address_obj)
is

begin

insert into billing_address values
(pi_address.house_no,pi_address.street,pi_address.city,pi_address.state,pi_address.pincode);
commit;
end save_address;
```

Getting error:

> [Error] PLS-00201 (15: 1): PLS-00201: identifier 'STREET' must be declared,
>   [Error] PLS-00201 (16: 1): PLS-00201: identifier 'CITY' must be declared,
>   [Error] PLS-00201 (17: 1): PLS-00201: identifier 'STATE' must be declared,
>   [Error] PLS-00201 (18: 1): PLS-00201: identifier 'PINCODE' must be declared,
>   [Error] ORA-00984 (20: 61): PL/SQL: ORA-00984: column not allowed here

Comment: Your procedure compiles for me. I think either you have not shown the part of the code that is failing or is it something else?. Also, while inserting, it is a good practice to specify column names.

Comment: Yes, I executed your ddl as well and had no errors thrown. I also created an anonymous block to invoke the procedure and that worked fine.

Comment: The error description PLS-00201 says =>>>  "an item to which no privilege was granted or an item to which privilege was granted only through a role." what does this mean? Do an object need a grant?

Comment: You are the only one getting those errors, unfortunately. Does `(15: 1)` mean line 15 column 1 or line 1 column 15? Your procedure only has 9 lines, so either way `(20: 61)` isn't from the demo code you posted.